# Running pyinstrument in a for loop will cause memory usage to continuously increase

Tags: python-3.x, profile

my python version is 3.7.9.

```
from pyinstrument import Profiler
import gc

def a():
    profiler = Profiler()
    profiler.start()
    a=1+1
    b=a+2
    profiler.stop()
    profiler.output_text(unicode=True, color=False, show_all=False, )
    profiler.reset()
    profiler = None
    del profiler
    gc.collect()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(100000000):
        a()
    pass
```

When I use pyinstrument, using it in a loop causes memory to continuously increase.
If these two lines ‘del profiler’ and ‘gc.collect()’ are not present, memory will grow very quickly.
How can I completely solve the problem of continuous memory growth?
My actual scenario is to apply it in Flask to count task time, but unfortunately, it also has a memory leak problem.
How to solve it.

```
@app.before_request
def start_timer():
    g.profiler = Profiler()
    g.profiler.start()
    request.start_time = time.time()


@app.after_request
def log_request(response):
    total_time = time.time() - request.start_time
    logging.info(f"{total_time :.2f}")
    g.profiler.stop()
    if total_time > 10:
        logging.info(g.profiler.output_text(unicode=True, color=False, show_all=False, ))
    g.profiler.reset()
    g.profiler = None
    return response
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to create a new `Profiler` object every time? Can't you do `g.profiler = Profiler()` in a `@app.before_first_request` step?

Comment: @Matthieu I referred to the official document https://pyinstrument.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#profile-a-web-request-in-flask, it is written like this in the example, and I have tried it, only creating once, and calling it continuously afterwards will also cause memory overflow.